# How to create SQL functions with a variable amount of input?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to create a function that joins a specified column from any table to my main table. My intended use of the function is as below:

```
Select *
From [Main Table] A
Outer Apply get_Factor([Table1], [Column_Name], Col1, [Key1]                ) As [Factor_A]
Outer Apply get_Factor([Table2], [Column_Name], Col2, [Key2]                ) As [Factor_B] 
Outer Apply get_Factor([Table9], [Column_Name], Col1, [Key1], Col2, [Key2]) As [Factor_C]
```

The function is essentially a join but I couldn't figure out now to make it to have a dynamic amount of keys.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[get_Factor]
(   
  @Table_Name VARCHAR(10)
, @Column_Name VARCHAR(10)
/* not sure how to add a dynamic amount of keys here. There can be more than 3 keys. */
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT @Column_Name
FROM @Table_Name
WHERE @Col1 = @key1 And @Col2 = @key2 And @Col3 = @key3 /* ...etc */
)
GO
```

The columns should be strings (e.g. 'Company Code') while the keys should be variables from the main table (e.g. [Company Code]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no hope of working. You cannot replace *identifiers* in queries with parameters, so you cannot use `@table_name` or `@column_name` as you intend.

The obvious solution is to use dynamic SQL. However, dynamic SQL is not permitted in SQL Server user-defined functions.

There are arcane options to get around this, such as:

- Write a CLR function that opens a new connection with SQL Server.  That is ridiculously complicated for this purpose.
- Use a stored procedure, but then you cannot use the function in a query.

Or, find some other way to accomplish what you want. It is possible that your need for such a function is driven by a poor data model, so fixing the data model would simplify your queries.